# Kali 2.0 won't boot after dual booting with Windows 10?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kali-linux

I installed Windows 10 64-Bit and I booted into that and it works amazingly. After I installed Windows 10 I partitioned a 80GB partition on my HDD and I continued to install Kali. No problems were present during the install but when it rebooted (after it was done installing) I choose Kali and well it won't boot. It says the normal [OK]  and after that my screen clears and a "_" is present in the top left of my display.

How can I successfully boot into Kali?

Thanks for the help ^_^